# How many hard drives can I attach to a Pi 5 when using it as a server?

Tags: pi-5

Yay! The Pi 5 is here!

I current have an old (5+ years, as least) Windows desktop:

AMD A6-7400K Radeon R5, 6 Compute Cores 2C+4G     3.50 GHz

with 6 harddrives attached - 4 directly from the motherboard, and 2 by USB - which I use as backup server (I have a lot to backup :-)

Could the Pi 5 replace it? Would it perform better? Is there any more info I can provide in order to help you to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could the Pi 5 replace it? Would it perform better?

Almost certainly not.  One the one hand we have a dual core x86-64 processor that goes to 3.5Ghz. On the other, a quad core ARM processor that goes to 2.5Ghz.

Now take into account that x86-64 systems are pound-for-pound significantly faster than ARM64 systems because ARM prioritizes stuff like small form factor and lower power use -- ie., the two ISAs are **not** really intended to compete with each other, which is why you have lots of ARM64 phones<sup>1</sup> and very few x64 ones (which tend to be at the high end of the market), and lots of x64 laptops but relatively few ARM64 ones (which tend to be at the low end of the market).

On top of that, the Pi 5 has *no hardware video acceleration* -- even previous Pi models had that. Instead, the intent is for video processing to occupy one of the cores when necessary, which, depending what you use your computer for, might be quite a bit of the time.<sup>2</sup>

It's notable that there does not as yet seem to be an intention to release a "Pi 500" in-keyboard portable desktop paralleling the Pi 400.

Finally, if it matters to you, keep in mind there will never be any version of Windows that runs on the Pi 5.

> 6 harddrives attached

You perhaps could get away with this if you used a powered USB hub...or two, since presuming the 3.0 ports can both be used at spec (which previous pi models have not always lived up to), you probably don't want to multiplex 6 on one port.

---

1. In relation to this, consider that a smartphone with the Pi 5 specs would be a budget, and not performance, device at this point.
2. You mention the old AMD Windows box is used as a "backup server", so this may not matter, although it is then unclear what you mean by "performance" here.  Chances are it isn't processor intensive anyway, and more about network to storage throughput, which the Pi likely won't match either.  However, one thing it would give you is a significantly lower power system. So it may be worthwhile if you re-think your actual needs in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I have 40+TB via 8 usb hdds attached via a 4 port hub in each usb 3 port of a raspi 4 and it works fine as a sharebox (btrfs redudancy, gocryptfs, samba, syncthing). For a while I even ran plex on it too. It never exceeds 40% memory usage on the 8gb model.

I'll be upgrading it to a raspi 5 this month, and adding plex back into it.

Usb hdds have a max 5gbps of bandwidth, the usb 3 ports on a raspi 5 have 10gbps each. So with 4 usb hdds on each usb 3 port you are at 2.5gbps each drive which would be typical performance anyway.

The rpi 5 has much better gpu performance and it has builtin crypto. So should be fine for plex.

If you are wanting a powerhouse, minisforum have rdna3/zen4/ryzen7xxx machines for $300usd or so which have far more ports and power, including hardware av1 encoding.